# How to change the size of child widget when the parent size changes?

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have 2 widgets, second widget is child of first one. I thought that if you change the size of the parent widget, the child widget will also change its size, but it's not. I searched the internet for a solution to my problem, but maybe I did not correctly formulate my question when looking for a solution. I did not find a solution and therefore wrote here.

What should I do to make child widget change its size when the parent is resized?

Comment: You should use layouts. You can read more about them [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: @Rhathin I know what layout is but how do I use it in this case? The problem is that I need to put child widget in any place (and move it anywere, for ex. move child widget to 1 pixel to right) of parent widget but layouts place widgets not how I want. They place widgets in special order that depends on layout. Or maybe I don't know something about layouts?

Comment: 1. Custom layout. 2. Custom resize handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cause

To automaticaly respond to the size changes of its parent widget, a child widget has to be added to its layout.

## Solution

Since you do not want to use automatic layout, you have to resize the child widget manually. For that purpose reimplement `QWidget::resizeEvent` in your custom widget.

## Example

Provided you have a pointer to your child widget `m_child` and this child is already positioned and resized, e.g. something like that:

```
m_child->move(10, 20);
m_child->resize(60, 40);
```

a possible implementation of the `resizeEvent`, preserving the margins, i.e. the distance between the edges of the child and the edges of the parent, could be the following:

```
void ParentWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);

    int oldWidth = event->oldSize().width();

    if (oldWidth >= 0)
        m_child->resize(m_child->width() + event->size().width() - oldWidth,
                        m_child->height() + event->size().height() - event->oldSize().height());
}
```

The full code of the example I have prepared for you is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-ParentChildSize).

**Note:** The reimplementation of the `QWidget::paintEvent` in the example is purely for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I already did this, but without using the resize() method. But now I copied your resizeEvent code. That's not complete solution. On my child widget there is a diagonal line from top-left to down-right corner (made by QPainter). Child widget placed in center of parent widget. So when I resize parent widget my diagonal line resizes too but it has pivot point in top-left corner.

Comment: (continue) When I resize my parent widget and make it smaller in width the line is becoming vertical line and then disappears. I need to move pivot point too in proportion with parent widget. For ex. pivot point is in place that is 20% of parent width. I'm resizing parent to smaller width and pivot point still should be on place that is 20% of new parent width size. And so with height. The question is how do I properly move this pivot point?

Comment: @Flone, no, the question is _How to change the size of child widget when the parent size changes?_ If you have another problem, post a new question with enough details for someone to be able to help.

Comment: @Flone, _But now I copied your resizeEvent code. That's not complete solution_. Of course it is not a complete solution. How could it be, when you didn't provide those details originally. However it is working and demonstrates how to accomplish what you have asked about. Again, if you have another problem, namely _how do I properly move this pivot point_, ask a new question, targeting this specific issue.

Comment: well thanks for the info anyway. I'm glad that you have took your time to answer to such noob as me.

Comment: and I know how to move pivot point but I have some problems with it. will see if I fix this thing.

Comment: @Flone, instead of getting frustrated, please try to understand how it works. It is not about being noob (I never said that). But when you ask on Stack Overflow, you get help with the specific question you have asked, not with all the problems you have with your project. The thing I've suggested is perfectly normal. You've shared an issue you have, you've received some quality answers and comments. Now share the other issue, you have and you will get help from someone for sure. I would be glad to take a look and help if I am able to. But is goes about another question, although connected.

Comment: first of all I will try to fix this problem by myself. And maybe then I'm gonna create a new question here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the no-layouts solution is quite obvious: override `resizeEvent` method in your parent and drive the children resizing from there.

On the other hand, keeping the child widget in the parent widget layout would grant it would resize along with its parent automatically, but your issue is: how to set the child widget position to a coordinate of choice?

I suggest a technique.

Say you want the child to move horizontally. Give the parent a `QHBoxLayout` layout (set the layout margins and spacing properties to `0`), and add the child to it, so it will take the whole space, horizontally. Then add a `QWidget` to the same layout, at the child left: this widget will act as a filler. If you want the child `x` be 42, set the filler `width` to 42, using its `setFixedWidth` method, programmatically, or set its minimum and maximum width to 42 from designer.

Obviously, if you have many children, and they can move anywhere (and overlap, maybe) drop layouts altogether and resort to my very first suggestion, because, generally speaking, layouts are intended to keep things anchored to each others, and maybe that's not the case.